# How to make a C# Windows app available in console and GUI modes?

Tags: c#, console

I have created an C# application, I need to access to my app in 2 modes:

1. GUI:
   via mouse or via ms dos console like this: `app.exe`
2. CommandLine:
   via ms dos console like this(without GUI interface): `app.exe -c <some_other_options>`

The problem when I configured my application like `Windows Application` The console version is not launched. But when I changed it to `Console Application` it launched with command line in 2 desired modes but when I launch it via click by mouse I had a black console opened with my gui and when I close the black console, the GUI is also closed.

Is it possible to make my need via c#?

There is my main function:

```
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {           
            var options = new Options();
            var parser = new CommandLineParser(new CommandLineParserSettings(Console.Error));

            if (args.Count() != 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!parser.ParseArguments(args, options))
                        Environment.Exit(1);
                    customfunc(options);
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Fatal error on parsing: " + e.Message);
                    Environment.Exit(1);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new frmApp());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you just asking how to avoid opening the window? Is the GUI WPF or winforms? "How do I do this specific thing in the framework I'm using? P.S. also please guess which framework."

Comment: @EricJ. this is my main function

Comment: Yes it's WPF or winforms? Excellent! We've narrowed it down!

Comment: Yes just for avoid opening black console :) I have used the GUI proposed by default in vs2012, I don't know because I'm newer in C# and ms technologies, How to know that?

Comment: Is the base class of your window called Window, or Form?

Comment: `public partial class frmApp : Form`

Answer (score 2):

One way I could see it is to have 3 assemblies :

- 1 common class library project (where you'd put all your logic code
- 1 Windows Forms (or WPF) exe app
- 1 console application project

Both the winforms and console app would reference the same common library for the background logic, and you only have implement the UI part in each app project. The only problem with that is that you'll have to have 2 different executable for each of the applications.

I do think there might be a way to do what you want in the same app, but I have no idea how to make the console app not show the console window.